# could be famously cruel (famously = very vs well known)

Tags: word-meaning

Can "famously" be translated as "very", or only as "well known"? For example, in this sentence:

> ... co-founder of Apple, who **could be famously cruel** with job seekers.

Source: English File - Upper-Intermediate.

Comment: Who wrote this? I would rather see ' co-founder of Apple, who, famously, could be cruel to job seekers'.

Comment: "Who was well known to be [sometimes] cruel to job-seekers" _Famously_ doesn't mean _very_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I have written about "very" because in this dictionary exists this definition (3 position):
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/famously

Comment: That's very odd, and no other online dictionary includes that definition.

Comment: From M-W : _**1: in a celebrated manner**, 2: in a superlative fashion, 3: to an unusual degree : VERY_  the word does not have to partake of all these meanings at once, and 'celebrated' is not necesarily positive.

Comment: *who could be famously X* is just a stylised way of saying ***known for being very X** [on occasion].*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means both "well known" and "very".

It's rare that I disagree with my beloved M-W, but I think definition 3 of "famously" falls short. To be "famously X" *always* means that you are *well known* for being *very* X, except where "X" itself includes the meaning of "not very", which we'll get to below.

In the OP example, this co-founder of Apple is necessarily *very cruel*, and cannot be just *somewhat* cruel.

To tease out the real meaning, let's contrast some minimally different sentences:

> 1a My sister is **known for being** good a chess.

This means she's good at chess, and many people identify her as a good player.

> 1b My sister is **famously** good at chess.

This means she's *very* good at chess, and many people identify her as a *very* good player. Note that the only difference here is how good she is at chess. She isn't necessarily famous or celebrated.

Now, let's try and force the issue:

> 1c My sister is **famously very** good at chess.

The "very" is redundant. It doesn't change the meaning of the sentence. This shows that "very" is part of the meaning of "famously".

What if we go farther?

> 1d My sister is **famously somewhat** good at chess.

This is probably meaningless, like someone being "extra average" at chess. The only way this could make sense is if she's expected to be brilliant at chess --like maybe our parents were both grandmasters-- but she's merely somewhat good. Even then, it's clunky, and should really read, "*... famously **only** somewhat good...*".

> 1e My sister is **famously average** at chess.

This sentence, surprisingly, is idiomatic English, but it's an indirect way of saying she's well known for being a bad player, not an average player.

Comment: It's a ***very*** context-specific implication (pun intended! :) So no surprise if we can't find it explicitly referenced in dictionaries. I like your "famously good / average" examples for showing the different context-specific "very / merely" implications. Another one that occurs to me is if there was a famous team in a male-dominated sport that somehow managed to include a *female* player. She might well be referenced as ***famously female*** even if there was endless public debate over her "true" gender (i.e. - she might not be remotely "feminine", as usually associated with "female").

Comment: @gotube, Thank you for your nice answer. Could you say, please, what means "famously said"? Is it someone's very common expression?

Comment: @Sergei What do you think it means?

Comment: @gotube, I had written my suggestion - a well-known phrase. Is it right?

Comment: @Sergei It means, "Someone is famous for having said X"

Answer (score 2):

Despite the dictionary definition you cited, I can't say that 'famously' can mean 'very' and *not* still mean "well known". You couldn't, for example, say that a cup of tea was 'famously hot'.

I suppose it can mean both, as its primary meaning leads to the other. If someone is 'famous' for being cruel, it would be unlikely that reputation came from just a few isolated incidents. One would expect that there must have been many repeated examples of that cruelty over a sustained period of time for that fame (or infamy) to come about.

Including 'famously' in this sentence does add weight to it in a similar way that an emphasising word like 'very' would, but that emphasis comes from the fact that the person *is* famous for this.